# Где разместить сервер?

Tags: сервер

Всем привет,
хочу попробовать разместить сервер в дата-центре, проект только на стартапе, поэтому хотелось бы поэкономней. Подскажите, на какую сумму ориентироваться, цены везде разные, на что надо обращать внимание?
Всем добра!

Comment: Вы хотите свою машину принести в датацентр?

А так - посмотрите на https://www.digitalocean.com/pricing/ (5долл самый дешевый тарифный план) и http://vdsina.ru/ (149 руб/месяц).

Comment: А насчёт облака не думали? Тот же Azure или S3. Не самый дешеый вариант, но если попрёт рост, то скалируемость будет высокой.

Comment: нужно ещё уметь писать код, который будет "скалироваться".

Comment: Ну для этого большого ума не надо. Просто лишь если приложение содержит состояния, то состояния не должны храниться на самом сервере. Но это уже другой вопрос и другая тема.

Comment: @Merk95, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Немного дополню @KoVadim.

###[DO](https://www.digitalocean.com/pricing/)

**Плюсы:**

- Довольно недорогой (мин. тариф 5$)
- Входит в [5-ку лучших хостинг провайдеров](http://www.datacenterknowledge.com/archives/2014/11/14/netcraft-digitalocean-now-third-largest-cloud/). Послушать [обсуждение на радио-т](http://archive.rucast.net/radio-t/media/rt_podcast418.mp3).
- Введите [промо-коды](https://bestcoupon.store/coupons/digitalocean-promo-code/) при регистрации и получите 10$ бонуса на аккаунт ))
- Хорошая поддержка со стороны [комьюнити (туториалы и не только)](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/)
- Довольно хорошая распределёность дата-центров (Нью Йорк, Сан-Франциско, Амстердам, Лондон, Сингапур)
- В этом году планируют [разместить дата-центр в Германии](http://habrahabr.ru/post/245787/) - территориально ближе, чем Амстердам. Можете [поддержать нашу глубинку](http://digitalocean.uservoice.com/forums/136585-digitalocean/suggestions/4248524-russia-data-center).
- web-интерфейс в стили минимализма

**Минусы:**

- Оплата в валюте. Есть возможность оплатить [через PayPal](http://digitalocean.su/registr)

###[VDSina](http://vdsina.ru/pricing/)

**Плюсы:**

- Оплата в рублях (мин. тариф 149 руб.)
- После регистрации и пополнения баланса [дарят 200 руб](https://vk.com/vdsina?w=wall-71153312_167).

**Минусы:**

- Молодой (репутацию только предстоит заслужить)
- Отсутствует [private networking](https://www.digitalocean.com/company/blog/introducing-private-networking/).
- [Один дата-центр в Амстердаме](https://qa.vdsina.ru/q/v-kakom-data-tsentre-nakhodyatsya-servery)
- web-интерфейс в виде переработанной ISP-панели. В течении года обещают сделать, как у "взрослых".

О всех плюсах, минусах и чаяниях можно [узнать из первых уст в devzen подкасте](http://devzen.ru/episode-0020/)

Последний использую для VPN, подумываю перевести всё свои PET-проекты.

**P.S.** Настраиваю всё руками (вернее, активно пользуюсь инструментами по управлению конфигурацией. На данный момент [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com)), и потому у меня нет необходимости использовать дроплет с предустановленным ПО (CMS и иже с ними)

Comment: А в DO если будет превышена нагрузка на сервер, то мне счет за этот оверлимит придет, да? И если так, то можно как-то просто при оверлимите ложить клауд?

Comment: [Оверлимит 2 цента за 1ГБ](http://goo.gl/gVWZZF). Если Вы заметили, то пока плата не взимается. Об этом я ещё слышал [здесь](http://youtu.be/euuH3fidpu4?t=3m58s).

Если честно, не один из проектов компании не достиг лимита (тарифы 10$ - 2ТБ и 20$ - 3ТБ). 

Чтобы достигнуть лимита у Вас должен быть один из следующих сценариев:

 * Видеохостинг или стрим аудио без компрессии (вещание подкаста) 
 * Аудиохостинг с высокой посещаемостью
 * Файловое хранилище с высокой посещаемостью
 * ...

Comment: @Jeremen1 Сервер недостаточно отключить, требуется удалить дроплет,предварительно сделав снапшот для последующего восстановления. 

 * ["Мощный API"](http://goo.gl/LXSNCx)
 * [Туториал](http://goo.gl/rw492t)

Answer (score 0):

я пользую этот: https://ultravds.com/
для стартапа не плохо... написать им письмо с просьбой дадут неделю теста.

Answer (score 0):

https://bandwagonhost.com/

vps на openvz всего за 10 баксов в год.

Answer (score 0):

оптимальные расценки нашел здесь:
http://www.mediasap.ru